# How do I introduce a new parameter all the way up the call hierarchy?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, intellij-14

Sometimes I want to introduce a new parameter at the bottom of a call stack and pass it all the way through to the top of the call stack.  This is annoying because I have to use the "extract parameter" refactoring over and over again in the same way.  Is there a shortcut to do this all the way up the call stack?

Here's some documentation on the topic of extract parameter: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/extract-parameter-in-java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a blog article on the topic here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/02/new-refactorings-around-the-call-hierarchy/

[image]